# Iterating through an array and play notes

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have an array which is populated by MusicNotes. Each MusicNote is an object with it's properties, e.g. pitch and duration. Duration is created using a timer in the MusicNote class.

The problem is that when I iterate through the array and play all the sounds the duration of each MusicNote is lost and it will play the whole wav file (for each note).

I know that the problem is related to the timer and I know that it maybe related to the Play() method in the MusicNote but I don't have any ideas on how to fix it. I have posted my the code related to this problem.

```
public class MusicNote : PictureBox
    {
        Timer tmr1 = new Timer();
        int tmr1duration;
        public SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
        public Timer tmr = new Timer();
        public int pitch;        //The no. of the music key (e.g. the sound freuency).
        public int noteDuration; //Shape of note.
        public string noteShape;
        static int xLoc = 0;
        int yLoc = 100;

        public MusicNote(int iPitch, int iNoteDuration)
            : base()
        {
            pitch = iPitch;
            noteDuration = iNoteDuration;
            Size = new Size(40, 40);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MusicNote_MouseClick);
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MusicNote_MouseDown);
            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(MusicNote_MouseUp);
            tmr1.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr1_Tick);
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(ClockTick);
        }

        public void ShowNote()
        {
            if (this.noteDuration == 1) noteShape = "Quaver.png";
            if (this.noteDuration == 4) noteShape = "Crotchet.png";
            if (this.noteDuration == 7) noteShape = "minim.png";
            if (this.noteDuration == 10) noteShape = "DotMin.png";
            if (this.noteDuration == 12) noteShape = "SemiBreve.png";
            this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(noteShape);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Location = new Point(xLoc, yLoc);
            xLoc = xLoc + 40;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            sp.SoundLocation = this.pitch + ".wav";
            sp.Play();
            //Timer to play the duration
            this.tmr.Interval = 100 * this.noteDuration;
            this.tmr.Start();
        }

        void ClockTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp.Stop();
            tmr.Stop();
        }

        private void MusicNote_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class were I have the array...

```
   public class MusicStaff: Panel
    {
        public ArrayList musicNotes = new ArrayList(); //Array to store the Music Notes.
        SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();

        public void AddNote(MusicNote newNote)         //Method to add the notes.
        {
            musicNotes.Add(newNote);
        }

        public int ListSize()
        {
            return musicNotes.Count;                   //Returns the size of the list.
        }

   public void PlayAll()
    {
        foreach (MusicNote m in musicNotes)
        {
            m.Play();
        }
```

I have removed some code from the classes which is not replated to the problem so that question is not too long. Any help how can I solve this would be greatly appreciated. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void PlayAll()
{
    foreach (MusicNote m in musicNotes)
    {
        m.sp.Stop();
        m.sp.PlaySync();
        Thread.Sleep(m.noteDuration); //duration should be in milliseconds
    }
}
```

Should this work you can remove your timer completely.

I suggest you look into the use of Properties in C# to not let fields be public.
By the way I did this assignment two years ago :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this is not working, I need the timer in MusicNote to be able to assign values to the noteDuration.... is it the case were I need to place another timer in MusicStaff as well? I would like to avoid this since I have already one in MusicNote..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `Sleep` on UI thread. It will block your application.

Comment: What do you recommend then?

Comment: Encapsulate the Music code into a separate class and expose an async method. That way your main thread can run the code in async and you will not be sleeping the UI thread.